Playwright results in an empty array when going to another page during a loop
I am trying to parse a page with Playwright.
The page has a table and each row contains data including a URL that I want to have Playwright goto, grab extra information and then add it to the row object that I am saving.
It works fine until I add the code to visit the newPage in which case I get an empty array.
I have a feeling it has to do with using await within a map function? Can someone offer some guidance?
const browserType = "chromium";
const url = "https://page-with-table.html";
const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
const context = await browser.newContext();
const page = await context.newPage();

await page.goto(url);

const tableRowsLocator = page.locator("table tr");

const tableData = await tableRowsLocator.evaluateAll(async (tableRows) => {
  const data = [];

  tableRows.map(async (tableRow) => {
    const rowObject = {};

    const rowData = tableRow.querySelector('td[data="rowData"]');

    const url = tableRow.querySelector('td[data="url"] a');

    // --- Problem code begins

    const newPage = await context.newPage();

    await newPage.goto(url);

    const contentLocator = newPage.locator("#content");

    const contentData = await contentLocator.evaluate(async (content) => {
      return content.textContent;
    });

    rowObject.content = newPageData;

    await newPageData.waitForTimeout(1000);
    await newPageData.close();

    // --- Problem code ends

    rowObject.rowData = rowData.textContent;
    rowObject.url = url.getAttribute("href");

    data.push(rowObject);
  });

  return data;
});

await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
await browser.close();

console.log(gamesData);


There are multiple issues here. Yes, map and async aren't compatible, unless you're using Promise.all. Probably you want a for .. of loop. Secondly, the code inside of evaluateAll's callback runs in the browser, and no Playwright code will work there because Playwright code runs in Node. What is the actual link for https://page-with-table.html, or the HTML content you're scraping, and the expected output? See this for a standard table scraping pattern in Playwright.

Don't use map, forEach, etc with async in Playwright.
  const tableRowsLocator = page.locator("table tr");
  const tableData = await tableRowsLocator.all();
  for (const tableRow of tableData) {
    const rowData = tableRow.locator('td[data="rowData"]');
    const url = tableRow.locator('td[data="url"] a');
    // your code
  }

